# Node/Protractor Wait for promise to resolve before continuing

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm writing a class that gets seleniumCapabilites and stores the values within the class. It exposes a method that uses the session got in the class to get the selenium node. However when javascript class calls my new class the getSeleniumNode returns undefined. I'm pretty sure this is because of the getSeleniumNode not waiting for the web request to finish processing but I'm not sure how to redesign it to work

```
    var base = require(__paths.e2e.pages + '/base'),
    urlParse = require('url-parse'),
    request = require('sync-request');

module.exports = function (options) {
    var self = base(options);


    browser.getProcessedConfig().then(function (config) {
        self.seleniumHub = new urlParse(config.seleniumAddress);
        console.log(self.seleniumHub.host);

        browser.driver.getCapabilities().then(function (capabilities) {
            self.capabilities = capabilities;

        });
    });

    self.getSessionId = function () {
        return self.capabilities.caps_[
            'webdriver.remote.sessionid'];
    };

    self.getPlatform = function () {
        return self.capabilities.platform;
    };

    self.getBrowserName = function () {
        return self.capabilities.browserName;
    };

    self.getBrowserVersion = function () {
        return self.capabilities.version;
    };

    self.getSeleniumNode = function () {
        var url = 'http://' + self.seleniumHub.host + "/grid/api/testsession?session=" + capabilities.caps_[
            'webdriver.remote.sessionid'];
        var response = request('GET', url);
        var testSession = JSON.parse(response.getBody().toString());
        return new urlParse(testSession.proxyId);
    };

    return self;


};
```

and my class which is calling this is

```
var base = require(__paths.e2e.pages + '/base');
var seleniumCapabilities = require(__paths.e2e.lib + '/seleniumCapabilities')();


module.exports = function (options) {
    var self = base(options);

    console.log(seleniumCapabilities.getSeleniumNode());




    return self;

};
```

The relevant console output I get when I run this e2e test is

```
undefined -- this is the call from       console.log(seleniumCapabilities.getSeleniumNode());

localhost:4444 --- this is the call from       console.log(seleniumCapabilities.getSeleniumNode());
```